# Removing a line from file that contains an inputted word

Tags: c, file, line

I've been trying to remove whole lines in a file (.txt) where a line contains the number ('1234' for example) using C. The number is given through scanf input.

Note that the line contain whitespaces, such as: `Bob 1234 Apple Tree`

I was wondering if someone could explain to me a method that could work effectively.

Thanks.

Comment: And why is your code not effective, can you post it?

Comment: I'm quite new at C, so I tried the replica method where you would write to a new file, delete the old one and rename the new one to the old file's name. However it deletes all the lines - I ended up deleting it because it seemed like a tedious way to do it, and I seemed to have some semantic errors in my code. 



I'm hoping perhaps someone can show me an implementation or know where I could find what I'm looking for. I've seen some posts that delete lines given a line number, but not given a word in a line. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this help you to start:

```
char *in_file, *out_file, line[255];
FILE *fp1, *fp2;

in_file  = "input.txt";
out_file = "output.txt";

fp1 = fopen( in_file, "r" );
fp2 = fopen( out_file, "w" );

while ( fgets( line, sizeof( line ), fp1 ) != NULL ) {
  if ( strstr( line, "1234" ) ) {
     fputs( line, fp2 );
  }
}

fclose( fp2 );
fclose( fp1 );
```

Comment: You wouldn't miss the parentheses if you add `!= NULL`, Also `const char *in_file` is better than `char in_file[50]` because it doesn't limit the length of the filename string.

Comment: Awesome, this uses the logic I was using, I guess I did something wrong!

What I've done is leave change to `if (strstr(line, "1234"){}' then have 'else{ fputs(line, fp2};'. This makes sure that everything but the 1234 line is copied.

Thank you for your help! I'll try it again like this and let you know how I get on and select as solution!